# Extract/Compare only Year from DATETIME field in SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis

Trying to check if a datetime column has a year of less than 1754 in a derived column.. my expression goes

```
(YEAR([OffenseEndDate]) < 1754) ? (DT_DBTimeStamp)"1900-01-01 00:00:00" : [OffenseEndDate]
```

I keep getting an error from this. I've also piped the error to another file and the some of the dates look like this

```
0010-05-06 00:00:00
```

Not understanding why this method is not working in SSIS. I either want to null the dates that have year less than 1754 or just output 1900-01-01.

Comment: I tested out your case.I am not getting any error. For me, The column [OffenseEndDate] is datetime, and all the rows were of valid date. I tried date 1753-01-22 06:07:10.347, which I got result as 1900-01-01

Comment: May be you have invalid dates in the dataset.

Comment: most likely...any tricks to "fix" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try derived column code:

```
(DT_I4)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,20)[OffenseEndDate],1,4)) < 1754 ? (DT_DBTimeStamp)"1900-01-01 00:00:00" : [OffenseEndDate]
```